# How to set the classID of an mxArray filled with mxSetData?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to use `mex.h` header to convert a c++ program I wrote into a Matlab command and I don't get how their mxArray struct works.

Let say I have a `std::vector<float>` called `data` that I want to convert to an mxArray I can return back to matlab, I will have to do something like this right ?

```
mxSetData(plhs[0], static_cast<void*>(&(*(data.begin()))));
mxSetN(plhs[0], data.size());
mxSetM(plhs[0], 1);
```

But then how do matlab know the `mxClassID` of the `mxArray` I want to send is `mxSINGLE_CLASS` ? Why shouldn't I use `mxSetData` for double data ? And why doesn't `mxSetClassID` exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to pre-dfine `plhs[0]` as `float` type and then set the pointer.

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix( 1, data.size(), mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL );
void* oldAllocation = mxGetData( plhs[0] ); // for de-allocation
mxSetData(plhs[0], static_cast<void*>(&(*(data.begin()))));
mxFree( oldAllocation );
```

BTW, are you sure `data` is on the heap and won't be de-allocated when your mex function terminates?

---

Alternatively, if `data` is not too big, you can simply copy it into `plhs[0]` (this is what I usually do)

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix( 1, data.size(), mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL );
float* dst = (float*)mxGetData( plhs[0] ); 
for ( int i = 0 ; i < data.size(); i++ ) {
    dst[i] = data[i];
}
// or use memcpy instead of the loop
```

Comment: Ok first thanks for your answer. I am sure the data will be deallocated in fact I am not using a vector and I allocated the pointer using mexMalloc as advised in the help.

Comment: I must say your solution looks however highly illogical to me since you need to allocate twice the memory (maybe creating a small matrix could work no ?...anyway this is still ugly).

Comment: @matovitch so why don't you allocate the pointer using `mxCreateNumericMatrix` directly setting `plhs[0]`?

Comment: That's a better option...But I am still wondering why they did not provide something like `mxSetClassID` an idea ?